# Secure a WordPress website in 2019: one plugin or a combinations of them?

Tags: security

How do you guys work now days regarding WordPress and security?

Do you use plugins or you manually edit the core files to prevent attacks?

Out there there are really good plugins solutions, but for a beginner as me is difficult to know which one to use or how many of them to use.

Do you think that the combination of a security plugin and a firewall is enough together with security best practices?

Comment: Any of the articles from [this](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=wordpress+security+guide&t=lm&ia=web) list will be good for you as a starting point.

Comment: I would recommend starting here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend these basic things:

- Never touch core files!
- Always update core and plugins
- Use strong passwords
- Don't use abondoned plugins or themes
- Use a well maintained security plugin (like wordfence?)

Of course you can use more security tools and settings for server e.g., but this should be the basic.
Maybe there are more things to do for a good start I forgot.